# is there any tool to auto tidy up F# code

Tags: f#

Visual Studio doesn't offer automatic formatting for F#, is there any other editor I can use to automate that?

I would like it would  put reasonable white spaces in between arithmetic operators `(a+b)` goes to `(a + b)` or assignment operators `=`

Comment: I suspect there isn't anything like that yet. This is the kind of thing Resharper is good at for C# and there is a (young) [project](https://github.com/JetBrains/FSharper) to make an F# plugin for Resharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been developing [a source code formatter for F#](http://lonelypad.blogspot.dk/2013/04/developing-source-code-formatter-for-f.html). The source can be found [on Github](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas).

At the moment, a VS extension has been released [in Visual Studio gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/24ef5c87-b4e3-4c3b-b126-1064cc66e148). Integration to other IDEs and editors should be possible while the API and command line are already available.

The VS extension can handle the situations you described quite well via [formatting selection feature](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md#using-visual-studio-2012-extension).

Answer (score 2):

Generic code indentation is supported in FSharpMode in Emacs:
[Link to download site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsharp-mode/)
But it wont help you to do automatic white-space separation of operators, only indentation.

Maybe write a simple formatter based on Tomas Petriceks code for syntax highlighting?

[Link to FSharp.Formatting](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting)